# ASP.NET Site.Master got corrupted

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms, master-pages

My system restarted and my site.master file is corrupt.

It only show numbers as the content of the site.master.
[image]
Any way to recover this?

Comment: Source control?

Comment: @JohnWu, None. Still developing it on system. Not yet moved to any repo